# Keystore file '/Project-Folder/android/app/debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'debug' in react-native 0.60

Tags: android, react-native

I created a sample application with react-native version 0.60.

I am trying to run application in android. But I am getting this error `Keystore file '/Project-Folder/android/app/debug.keystore' not found for signing config 'debug'`.

I don't know how to resolve this error.

Comment: You can generate the debug keystore by running this command in the **yourproject/android/app/** directory: 
`keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

Answer (score 26):

just download the file from official template:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/template/android/app/debug.keystore

and move it to the directory `awesomeProject\android\app`

Answer (score 24):

You can generate the debug keystore by running this command in the `android/app/` directory:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

All credits to Chris Morbitzer:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25629#issuecomment-511209583